# SQL nested data running total until value reached

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, chrome-ux-report

I am trying to use a complex nested dataset on Google BigQuery using the tutorial here:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-user-experience-report/getting-started

The data exported as json looks like this:
https://gist.github.com/kmturley/c46eb3898d6ee62871f4402a4d2c6f7d

The example i'm using which works is:
https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/savedquery/226352634162:c5b7ee9ea0394728a821cf60f58737c2

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  effective_connection_type.name AS ect,
  SUM((
    SELECT
      SUM(bin.density)
    FROM
      UNNEST(first_contentful_paint.histogram.bin) bin
    WHERE
      bin.end <= 1000
      AND origin = 'http://example.com')) AS density
FROM
  `chrome-ux-report.chrome_ux_report.201710`
GROUP BY
  ect
ORDER BY
  density DESC
```

This outputs the data:

```
1   4G  0.6977   
2   3G  0.056    
3   slow-2G null     
4   2G  null     
5   offline null
```

However I would like to output the bin.end value (time), when SUM(bin.density) reaches 0.7. My expected output would look something like this:

```
1   4G  1000     
2   3G  50000    
3   slow-2G null     
4   2G  null     
5   offline null
```

Meaning on 4G connection, 70% (0.7) of page loads are less than 1.5 seconds (1500). I have tried to modify the script to be:

```
SELECT
  SUM(bin.density)
WHERE
  SUM(bin.density) <= 0.7
```

But this is not allowed, so tried:

```
SELECT
  SUM(bin.density) AS RunningTotal
WHERE
  RunningTotal <= 0.7
```

And also tried

```
SELECT
  SUM(bin.density) OVER() AS RunningTotal
WHERE
  RunningTotal <= 0.7
```

But this doesn't work either! How can I implement a running total with nested datasets? and have it output the bin.end time?

If I can't get nested datasets to work with SQL running totals, then my only other option is to flatten the dataset, and loop through each row with Python to calculate the result. Which is far less performant!

**Updated: Solution based on answer by Felipe Hoffa**

```
#standardSQL
SELECT origin, form, ect, `end`, density
FROM (
  SELECT origin, form, ect, `end`, density, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ect ORDER BY `end` DESC) rn
  FROM (
    SELECT origin, form, ect, bin.end, SUM(bin.density) OVER(PARTITION BY ect ORDER BY `end`) AS density 
    FROM (
      SELECT origin, form_factor.name form, effective_connection_type.name ect, first_contentful_paint.histogram
      FROM    `chrome-ux-report.chrome_ux_report.201710`
      WHERE    origin = 'http://example.com' AND form_factor.name = 'phone'
    ) , UNNEST(histogram.bin) AS bin
  )
  WHERE density < 0.7
) 
WHERE rn=1
```

https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/savedquery/88263730615:ba1906e86b074511a804660ec973de37

Comment: What does it mean to output the `bin.end` value? For each `etc`, you want to return an array of some subset of `bin.end` if the `density` for the group is at least 0.7? It would help if you gave an example of the desired output in your question.

Comment: Apologies, have updated question with expected results and clarification on what bin.end time is. The dataset is a little confusing, that's Google's not mine :)

Comment: Your question should not contain the solution. Please remove the solution and post an answer if you want to share your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a cumulative SUM() and sorting the results by connection:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ect, `end`, density
FROM (
  SELECT ect, `end`, density, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ect ORDER BY `end` DESC) rn
  FROM (
    SELECT  ect, bin.end, SUM(bin.density) OVER(PARTITION BY ect ORDER BY `end`) AS density 
    FROM (
      SELECT  effective_connection_type.name ect, first_contentful_paint.histogram
      FROM    `chrome-ux-report.chrome_ux_report.201710`
      WHERE    origin = 'http://example.com'
    ) , UNNEST(histogram.bin) AS bin
  )
  WHERE density < 0.7
) 
WHERE rn=1
```

[image]

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I needed! Although when I do the calculations manually they don't add up: https://gist.github.com/kmturley/c46eb3898d6ee62871f4402a4d2c6f7d adding all the values for 4G to 1000 gets me: 0.1504 + 0.1415 + 0.1262 + 0.0697 + 0.0473

Comment: Ah I believe it's adding desktop and mobile together. That's an easy fix. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Updated with my final solution. and link here: https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/savedquery/88263730615:ba1906e86b074511a804660ec973de37

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a subquery and a cumulative sum:

```
with cte as (
      <your query here>
     )
select x.*
from (select cte.*, sum(density) over (order by density desc) as runningtotal
      from cte
     ) x
where runningtotal - density < 0.7 and runningtotal >= 0.7;
```

Comment: How do you envision this outputting `bin.end`, though? Is the assumption that the CTE unnests `first_contentful_paint.histogram.bin`?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard . . . The assumption is that would all be done in the CTE.